# My var does not work with Blockchain API

Tags: python, api, bitcoin, blockchain

I try to connect check the amount of an BTC adress ( with the private key ).
I have the adress and key in a file. When i write the var directly is the python script it's work's but when i try to do the same with the var from the file it does not work. I have check my var after take them from the file ( with print ) and i also have check their type which is String.I also try to str() my two var but it's change nothing. I use python 3.4 on windows and the api from blockchain.info . Here the git doc : https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-python/blob/master/docs/wallet.md

```
sortieFichier = open(fichierSortie, 'a') 
fd = open(fichierClef, 'r')
n = 0
miniCompt=0
aTrouver=": "
for line in fd:
    n += 1
    miniCompt+= 1
    
    #extract the adress from the file
    if(miniCompt==1):
        adressBTC=str(line)
        tronc = adressBTC.find(aTrouver)
        adressBTC =adressBTC[len(aTrouver)+tronc:]
        
     
    if(miniCompt==2):
        # exctract the key
        clefBTC=str(line)
        tronc = clefBTC.find(aTrouver)
        clefBTC =str(clefBTC[len(aTrouver)+tronc:])
         
        print(clefBTC) # = 5J6jgMj4FhcT9y1###########################
        print(adressBTC) # = 1CBXtLZdv4jN9LGF5Dbs##############
        print(isinstance(clefBTC,int)) # return true
         

        # connect with the function to check the wallet 
        wallet = Wallet(clefBTC, '')
        addr = wallet.get_address(adressBTC, confirmations = 2) # Ligne 37 HERE ERROR
        amount=addr.balance
        amount=amount/100000000
        print(amount)
        if(amount>0):
            sortieFichier.write(adressBTC)
            sortieFichier.write(clefBTC)
            sortieFichier.write(amount)
        miniCompt=0
         
         
fd.close()
```

and here the error :

```
True
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
 
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\blockchain\monScript.py", line 37, in <mod
 
ule>
 
    addr = wallet.get_address(adressBTC, confirmation
 
s = 2)
 
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\blockchain\wallet.py", line 133, in get_ad
 
dress
 
    response = util.call_api("merchant/{0}/address_balance".format(self.identifi
 
er), params)
 
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\blockchain\util.py", line 23, in call_api
 
    response = urlopen(BASE_URL + resource, payload, timeout = TIMEOUT).read()
 
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 153, in urlopen
 
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
 
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 453, in open
 
    req = meth(req)
 
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1097, in do_request_
 
    raise URLError('no host given')
 
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>
```

It's very strange because if i write the key/adress instead of the var it's work :

```
wallet = Wallet('5J6jgMj4FhcT9y1###########################', '')
addr = wallet.get_address('1CBXtLZdv4jN9LGF5Dbs##############', confirmations = 2)
```

I apologize for my bad english and i'm still open for further explications

Answer (score 0):

invisible char come here : adressBTC =adressBTC[len(aTrouver)+tronc:]
So as the adresse is always the same size ( idem for key ) i do :
adressBTC =adressBTC[len(aTrouver)+tronc:len(aTrouver)+tronc+34]